# Evaluating the correctness of an equation.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that F = $F(x,y)$ is a function.

and suppose u and V are vectors such that u $ =\left( u_{x}, u_{y}  \right) $  and $\overrightarrow{V} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u_{x}}\overrightarrow{i} +  \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u_{y}}\overrightarrow{j}$

Is it true to say that $\displaystyle\iint_A \overrightarrow{\nabla}.\left( \delta u \overrightarrow{V} \right) dA$ $= \displaystyle\int_0^b \left[  \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u_x} \delta u \right]_{x=0}^{x=a} dy$ $+\displaystyle\int_0^a \left[  \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u_y} \delta u \right]_{y=0}^{y=b} dx$?

if not, then what is the amount of LHS?

Comment: A bit of pedantry here - $F(x,y)$ is not a function. $F$ is a function, $F(x,y)$ is a value.

Comment: @K.defaoite I would say that $F(x,y)$ is a function and $F(x_0,y_0)$ is a value, where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are fixed values.

Comment: This is not correct. See wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics) (go to the "notation" section)

Comment: $(x,y)\rightarrow F(x,y)$ is a function. The notation there to say the arguments are $x$ and $y$ looks fine to me.

Comment: Question edited